# How to use service/module inside of another module?

Tags: javascript, nestjs

In the main.ts file of my nestJS application I would like to add some fixture data to my database if the app is starting in dev mode:

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule)
await app.listen(port, async () => {

  if (!production) {
    const User = this.db.collection('user')
    await User.deleteMany({})
    await User.insertMany(user)
  }
})
```

Of course this is not working, as I do not have `db` at this time.

I'm defining the database connection in a module and this is how my database.module.ts looks like.
Is it possible to put the fixtures parts (drop database and add fixture data) in the database.module? The reason why I think I have to add it to the main.ts is that I need to run it on application start, not at every db connection.

```
import { Module, Inject } from '@nestjs/common'
import { MongoClient, Db } from 'mongodb'

@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'DATABASE_CLIENT',
      useFactory: () => ({ client: null })
    },
    {
      provide: 'DATABASE_CONNECTION',
      inject: ['DATABASE_CLIENT'],
      useFactory: async (dbClient): Promise<Db> => {
        try {
          const client = await MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017')
          dbClient.client = client
          const db = client.db('database')
          return db
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error)
          throw error
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  exports: ['DATABASE_CONNECTION', 'DATABASE_CLIENT']
})
export class DatabaseModule {
  constructor(@Inject('DATABASE_CLIENT') private dbClient) {}
  async onModuleDestroy() {
    await this.dbClient.client.close()
  }
}
```

With that I can use my db in every other module, but that doesn't help me to get db connection at start up of the application:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'
import { MyService } from './my.service'
import { MyResolvers } from './my.resolvers'
import { DatabaseModule } from '../database.module'

@Module({
  imports: [DatabaseModule],
  providers: [MyService, MyResolvers]
})
export class MyModule {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to get the database client in your `main.ts` you need to get into the client from the container system nest has. You can do that with the following line, used before your `app.listen()`

```js
const db = app.get('DATABASE_CLIENT', { strict: false })
```

And then instead of `this.db` you'll just use `db.client.collection()`

Comment: `TypeError: db.connection is not a function`. Doing `console.log(db.client)` gives me the client, but I don't understand how to get a specific collection...

Comment: Fixed some typos. Sorry about that

Comment: Still getting `TypeError: db.client.collection is not a function`

Comment: With your solution I have to do `db.client.db('database').collection('user')`, but I would like to use the already in the module configured db connection

Comment: Then you could probably use `DATABASE_CONNECTION` instead of `DATABASE_CLIENT`.

Comment: Why do I have to put your line before `listen` and not inside of it?

Comment: Technically you could do it inside of listen, but it doesn't really change anything. But convention is usually to do modifications before you start listening